# Combine models for resolving n+1 queries without scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got array of this data:

```
{user_id: 1, schedule_id: 4, some_more_fields: 'yup'}
```

it is a result of some data processing. As you could notice, this data is associated with user and schedule – so, for decent looking output I should print the name of the user and time of the schedule, for example.

This association's cannot be done with ActiveModel because of ActiveModel do not support relation's, but it can be done with active record tabless gem. But here come's a rapid fire of queries to a database: it triggers a query for an every record. It's classic and easily solve's by `includes`, but `includes` works only on scopes unfortunately (I've got only a Ruby-native Array).

I can solve this problem with manual mapping ids to a manual query and manually glue one to another to achieve one request for one entity, but I find this way extremely unattractive.

Is here more acceptable way?

UPDATE

Ok, let's dive a little bit deeper.
User isn't associated with Schedule. While schedule goes (it's a period of time) user's gain some stats (like rating). Then I need to summary – how much of good votes and bad votes user got. After that processing with some `group` SQL statements I get something like

```
[{user_id: 1, schedule_id: 4, good: 5, bad: 10},
{user_id: 2, schedule_id: 4, good: 80, bad: 0}
{user_id: 3, schedule_id: 4, good: 0, bad: 0}]
```

Then I'm trying to show this data in my view with something like

```
@tracks.each do |track|
  "#{track.user.name} got #{track.good} and #{track.bad} votes"
end
```

`track.user` is association through `user_id` which loads a user every hit. So my SQL input is

```
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
```

which is bad.
The only idea I get so far is to cache users in a hash, like

```
# cache
@users = { }
User.where(id: @tracks.map(&:user_id)).each do |user|
  @users[user.id] = user
end

# in view
@tracks.each do |track|
  "#{@users[track.user_id]} got #{track.good} and #{track.bad} votes"
end
```

But i find this way is unattractive. What should I do?

Comment: Can you post some more info about your models, and how User is associated with Schedule?

Comment: where did `@tracks` come from?

Comment: @tracks is the example above (3-element array). It comes from several group statement's and some afterwards processing. So, it's just plain array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand the question or more so the output you are looking for but you could try this

```
User.joins(:schedules).where(id:your_array.collect{|h| h[:user_id]},schedules:{id:your_array.collect{|h| h[:schedule_id]}})
```

This should generate:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN schedules ON schedules.id = users.schedule_id WHERE users.id IN (...) AND schedules.id IN(...)
```

Comment: Yup, it is. It's not a problem to solve it your way (and I'm doing the same thing) — but I find this method a little bit ugly. Thanks, anyway